# ASP.NET configuration error while rendering the controls on Production server

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-6

I am hosting a asp.net website on production server.

I am grtting asp.net error in rendering the controls on production server.

The stack trace of this error is :

Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.tribute_home_aspx.__RenderYTAnnouncement(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   ASP.tribute_home_aspx.__RenderForm1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) +62
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +163
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51
   System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +21
   FormRewriterControlAdapter.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +8685321
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   ASP.tribute_home_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) +851
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
```

I have tested my code fully but i could not find any error because the same code is working fine on the staging server.

I feel this is an error releated the Virtual directory configuration or asp.net configuration on Production server.

Please help to get rid off from this error as it has wested a lots of time already.

Prior Thanks,

Comment: try using Fiddler or other logging mechanism to see whats going on internally with your requests. Something hasn't obviously been instantiated properly somewhere. Also check if all the requisite DLLs are found on your deployment server and everything is being properly referenced.

Comment: Hello Amn, One another website is running on the same code and its workinmg fine on the same production server. We are trying to setup a new website on the copy of the same code in a different directory in wwwroot folder. I suspect that there may be some issue regarding configuration of Virtual directory. Can you please tell me if any configuration releated problem may create such a problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might sound superfluous. But check if you have the most up to date version of your ascx and or aspx files deployed.